How to over Come the apt update from a local repo , index files errors
Here is how I have configured my local repo server
root@aus-ntnx-ubuntu:/etc/apt# cat mirror.list
set base_path /var/spool/apt-mirror
set mirror_path $base_path/mirror
set skel_path $base_path/skel
set var_path $base_path/var
set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
set defaultarch amd64
set nthreads 20
set _tilde 0

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

And this I ran apt-mirror,
This is the output I got after running apt-mirror
root@aus-ntnx-ubuntu:/etc/apt# apt-mirror
Downloading 152 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  7 03:57:09 2024
[20]...
[19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]...                        [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Aug  7 04:10:44 2024

Processing translation indexes: [TTTT]

Downloading 178 translation files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  7 04:10:44 2024
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]...                        [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Aug  7 04:24:19 2024

Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DDDD]

Downloading 120 dep11 files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  7 04:24:19 2024
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]...                        [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Aug  7 04:37:54 2024

Processing cnf indexes: [CCCC]

Downloading 32 cnf files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  7 04:37:55 2024
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]...                        [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Aug  7 04:51:27 2024

Processing indexes: [PPPP]

156.6 GiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 68834 archive files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  7 04:51:33 2024
[20]...
[19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]...                        [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Aug  7 07:14:06 2024

1.1 GiB in 794 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)


Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
.

Here arrest directories which got downloaded.
root@aus-ntnx-ubuntu:/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool# du -sh *
22G main
8.2G    multiverse
16G restricted
134G    universe

after apt-mirror, I can access the http to the server where the repos are downloaded.
Here is my Client Side Configuration. and apt-update output
root@bcx-aus-6e2c375:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat aus-ub24-sources.list
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu./ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu./ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu./ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu./ubuntu noble-security main restricted universe multiverse

Then When I run my apt clean and apt-update I get errors.
root@bcx-aus-6e2c375:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt update
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of apt-news.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of esm-cache.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Get:1 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
Get:2 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Get:3 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease [126 kB]
Get:4 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
Ign:5 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Components
Ign:8 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main Icons (48x48)
Ign:9 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64)
Ign:10 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:11 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:12 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/restricted amd64 Packages
*****
****
*****
*****
****
Ign:90 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/restricted Icons (64x64)
Ign:91 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:92 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:93 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:94 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:95 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Components
Ign:96 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Icons (48x48)
Ign:97 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Icons (64x64)
Ign:98 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:99 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:100 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:101 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:102 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 Components
Ign:103 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (48x48)
Ign:104 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64)
Ign:105 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:106 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:20 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:27 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Err:10 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64@2)
  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
Get:29 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages [318 kB]
Get:30 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [82.9 kB]
Get:31 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Components [8,564 B]
Get:32 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Icons (48x48) [12.6 kB]
Get:33 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Icons (64x64) [15.1 kB]
x-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,808 B]
Get:102 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 Components [208 B]
Get:103 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (48x48) [29 B]
Get:104 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64) [29 B]
Ign:105 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Get:106 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [344 B]
Ign:34 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:41 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:48 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:55 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:60 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/main Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:65 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:72 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:77 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:84 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/main Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:91 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:98 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:105 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Err:34 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Icons (64x64@2)
  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
Ign:41 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:48 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:55 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-updates/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Err:60 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/main Icons (64x64@2)
  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
Ign:65 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:72 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:77 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Err:84 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/main Icons (64x64@2)
  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
Ign:91 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/restricted Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:98 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Icons (64x64@2)
Ign:105 http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse Icons (64x64@2)
Fetched 43.1 MB in 1s (40.3 MB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar  404  Not Found [IP: ip-hashed 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


This question is similar to: How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you actually have an HTTP server running on your mirror, serving these synced packages? And have you configured DNS or /etc/hosts or something on the second system so that aus-ntnx-ubuntu resolved to the first system?
